# Network-manager stops Working Every 1-2 hours

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

My wifi works fine on OSX but every hour or so my Ubuntu 16.04 system will disconnect and the only way I can reconnect is by restarting network-manager.

`dmesg | grep ath` yields nothing

`iwevent` around the point of disconnect, restart, and reconnect yields:

```
18:43:31.171770   wlp110s0 Scan request completed
18:44:10.635421   wlp110s0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated
18:44:11.667970   wlp110s0 Scan request completed
18:44:11.714947   wlp110s0 Association Response IEs:01088C129824B048606C2D1A6E101BFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000003D1695050500000000000000000000000000000000000000DD1
18:44:11.714976   wlp110s0 New Access Point/Cell address:F0:B2:E5:C1:DE:AC
18:44:15.075561   wlp110s0 New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` yields:

```
[43226.797176] iwlwifi 0000:6e:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
```

`lspci | grep Network` yields:

```
6e:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
```

`lsmod | grep iwlwifi` yields:

```
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              581632  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```